# InvalidOperationException: DataReader already active on this command

Tags: database, sqlite

An error occurred while attempting to create a DB through the Uniy.

Below is a DLL file created by referring to "Mono.Data.Sqlite".

```
public class DbCon
{
    private String Path;
    private SqliteConnection connection;
    private SqliteCommand Command;

    public DbCon(String nPath)
    {
        Path = nPath;
    }


    private string getCoonectingString()
    {
        string strCon = String.Format(@"Data Source={0};Version=3;New=True;Compress=False;Read Only=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True", Path);
        return strCon;
    }

    public bool IsConnected()
    {
        if (connection != null && connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public bool connect()
    {
        if (IsConnected() == true) return true;
        connection = new SqliteConnection(getCoonectingString());
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                Command = new SqliteCommand();
                Command.Connection = connection;
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private DataTable GetTable()
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Columns.Add("NAME", typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("EADATE", typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("LATIUDE", typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("HLTIUDE", typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("LRAD", typeof(Double));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("NRAD", typeof(Double));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("MRAD", typeof(Double));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("NNL", typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("CREATDATE", typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("EDITDATE", typeof(string));
        return dataTable;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// NAME
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>DataTable</returns>
    public DataTable GetNameListSel()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("NAME", typeof(string));
        String queryString = String.Format("SELECT DISTINCT NAME from IFPUG ");
        Command.CommandText = queryString;
        table.Load(Command.ExecuteReader());
        Command.ExecuteReader().Close();
        return table;
    }
}
```

This script was taken by referring to Unity.

```
void Start()
{
    string str = "C:/SEA.s3db";

    DbCon nCon;
    nCon = new DbCon(str);
    bool result = nCon.connect();

    Debug.Log(result);

    if (result == true)
    {
        table = nCon.GetNameListSel();
        Debug.Log("11");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("22");
    }
 }
```

I ran the function with the script above, but I checked to be connected, but I keep getting an error in the part where I run the function.

```
{InvalidOperationException: DataReader already active on this command}
```

I need your help. Please let me live.

Comment: Hey, I think you should move connection command initialization call to the `GetNameListSel` method to have maximum availability.

Comment: I tried but it's still has same error...